# having trouble deleting specific html element with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble deleting the specific element that the delete button is for, instead it deletes the last in the array, or the first with my previous code, any help is greatly appreciated. Vanilla js. 
Codepen: https://codepen.io/Adrw4/pen/LzvjLj

```
  idNum--;
  console.log(idNum);
  console.log(array);
  var node = document.getElementById(idNum);
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on the ID of the elements, just pass in the `event` to the `deleteTodoItem` function on click event. Based on the knowledge of the DOM, you can find out the related `li` element and delete it.

```
function deleteTodoItem(event) {
  var node = event.target.parentNode;
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
};
```

Here's the updated codepen:

https://codepen.io/Nisargshah02/pen/OxGjOr?editors=1010